# spring aop execution returning type

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I 
intercept  methods through AspectJ. And I need in pointcut expression `execution(* *.*(..))` add returning type TestObj. How can I do this?

```
@Around("@annotation(interceptor) && execution(* *.*(..)) && args(argType, ..)")
public Object logAction(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Interceptor interceptor, TestObj argType) throws Throwable {
    // do smth
}
```

Comment: Is it pure chance that the type of the first method parameter is also `TestObj`, just like the return type? Or is it a mistake and you actually want to bind the return value to a parameter? Because then `args()` would not do what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

The `execution()` expression supports the return type filtering. If you need the return type to be `TestObj`, or any of it's subtypes, following should work:

```
@Around("@annotation(interceptor) && execution(* TestObj *.*(..)) && args(argType, ..)")
public Object logAction(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Interceptor interceptor, TestObj argType) throws Throwable {
```

You can find more [in the official docs, Chapter 2. Annotations](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html#example-pointcuts):

> execution(public (@Immutable *) org.xyz..*.*(..))
>
> The execution of any public method in a package with prefix org.xyz, where the method returns an immutable result.

Comment: Compilation error wirh execution(* TestObj *.*(..)). I tried do execution(TestObj *.*(..)), but acpect does not intercept my function